# conditional event handler for mui chip onclick using react/typescript?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the following mui Chip declaration in a React/TypeScript app:

```
<Chip
    label={chipConfig.text}
    icon={chipIcon}
    // onClick={url && urlOnClick(url) : null}
    // {...(url && { onClick: urlOnClick(url) })}
/>
```

As you can see in the code snippet above, I'm trying to conditionally add an onclick handler to the Chip if a url variable has a variable.   But both attempts at the onclick handler above return errors.  Any idea what the proper implementation for this should look like?